# Azure Web App auth customize WWW-Authenticate challenge

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have Azure Web App with the Authentication blade configured to use Azure AD authentication:

[image: azureauth]

It works fine in the browser, but this ASP.NET Web API app is exposing OData feeds that will be consumed from Excel.

In Excel authentication should happen via Organizational account:

[image]

When clicking the sign-in button, I get an error for invalid authorization URI:

[image]

According to [some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-access-token-to-access-the-resource), the `WWW-authenticate` header should return `authorization_uri` like this:

`HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.com/oauth2/authorize",  error="invalid_token",  error_description="The access token is missing.",`

But since I use the pre-authentication features of Azure Web Apps, I can't control that directly from code.

Any idea if I can add configuration to Azure AD App manifest, or any other place where I can instruct it to do it "correctly"?

Comment: Microsoft already responded to our feedback post, with a time frame of ~2 weeks for a fix: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/32016403-azure-web-app-auth-customize-www-authenticate-chal?tracking_code=35cc2e94157cc35b2e0816d98d2d5b7d